# Collision Detection with javascript on the html canvas element without using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have something I can not wrap my head around, I have been trying for a couple of hours. I am making a simple game. I have most of the code done, but I cannot make collision detection work, now matter how hard I try

JS

```
function collision() {
//Tank1
if (bulcords2.x < tankcords.x + 31 &&
    bulcords2.x + 5 > tankcords.x &&
    bulcords2.y < tankcords.y + 31 &&
    1 + bulcords2.y > tankcords.y) {
  }
}
```

Comment: I suggest reading some materials, like http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-html5-game8/ and look forward to some framework, like tree.js, so you won't need to reinvent wheel. And why are you asking about not using jQuery, while Canvas has nothing to do with jQuery?

Comment: @Deele I think the OP *wants* to re-invent the wheel. And, what's "tree.js"? Can it be that you mean "three.js"? How's that going to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine a collision in one dimension, say X, consider this example

```
        x X               
........bbb............   // Bullet b, position 8 (x=8), width 3 (X=8+3)
          x   X
..........ttttt........   // Tank t, position 10 (x=10), width 5 (X=10+5)
```

a collision happens when

```
b.X >= t.x && b.x <= t.X
```

in other words

```
(b.x + b.width) >= t.x && b.x <= (t.x + t.width)
```

The same applies to the Y dimension. A collision in 2D space happens when there's one on both axes.

To spice things up I add a little prototype inheritance.

```
function GameObject(w, h) {
    this.width = w;
    this.height = h;
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    return this;
}
GameObject.prototype.collides = function (otherObject) {
    return (this.x + this.width) >= otherObject.x && 
           this.x <= (otherObject.x + otherObject.width) &&
           (this.y + this.height) >= otherObject.y &&
           this.y <= (otherObject.y + otherObject.height);
};
GameObject.prototype.move = function (x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    return this;
};
function Bullet() {
    return GameObject.call(this, 5, 5);
}
Bullet.prototype = new GameObject();
function Tank() {
    return GameObject.call(this, 31, 31);
}
Tank.prototype = new GameObject();
```

Test:

```
var tank = new Tank().move(10, 10); // 10,10 ; 41,41
var bullet = new Bullet(); // 0,0 ; 5,5

bullet.move(1, 8); // 5,4 ; 10,9
console.log( bullet.collides(tank) ); // logs false;

bullet.move(5, 5); // 5,5 ; 10,10
console.log( bullet.collides(tank) ); // logs true (NE edge);

bullet.move(41, 41); // 41,41 ; 46,46
console.log( bullet.collides(tank) ); // logs true (SE edge);

bullet.move(42, 42); // 42,42 ; 47,47
console.log( bullet.collides(tank) ); // logs false;
```

Comment: This solution looks good, unfortunately the OP probably needs a course on basic programming before understanding your additional inheritance code hehe. It's highly likely OP's code is referring to the sprite object values directly without any concept of model

Comment: So they have something to think about/some guidance, that's a good thing. If necessary the raw collision detection bit can be extracted and used on its own.

Answer (score 1):

Try box2dweb, Its javascript representation of box2d library of java. It has various physics features, like collision, gravity, weight, and much more. It is simple to use and will full fill your requirements.

**[Box2dWeb](https://code.google.com/p/box2dweb/)**