# Trying to make really simple collision in JS and Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have this game where I'm planning to make it into some kind of shooter (please also state if that's too hard considering the level I'm currently at) and I'm at the point of making things collide, like the player with point rectangles (should make orbs instead soon).

I've looked at different examples like
[Collision Detection with javascript on the html canvas element without using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27349650/collision-detection-with-javascript-on-the-html-canvas-element-without-using-jqu)
and
http://jlongster.com/Making-Sprite-based-Games-with-Canvas
but it seems like I didn't understand the code well enough. Here's what I have:

```
if( (rX + (rX + 20)) >= x && rX <= (x + 20) && (rY + (rY + 20)) >= y && rY <= (y + 20)){
    poeng++; 
    genererRandom();
}
```

Didn't work, so tried this one:

```
if (x >= rX || (rX+19) < (x+49) ||
    y >= rY || (rY+19) < (y+49)) {
    poeng++;
    genererRandom();
}
```

- x is the x position of the sprite I'm using (which is 60x60 large)
- y is the y of x
- rX is a randomly generated number and the x position of the point rectangle (again, think I should make it into orbs soon)
- rY is the y of rX

Also, just ask if you want to see more code, although it is mostly not mine, I was given an unfinished game that I could make something out of.

Comment: This may help you out http://canvascode.co.uk/Projects/SpaceDestroyer/maths.js

Comment: In addition to my answer below: consider writing all of your code in english. It makes sharing and helping easier in the long run. Also consider looking into object oriented JS if your code gets too complex at some point.

Comment: Yeah, i know, just didn't expect to share the code. I usually do write in English, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a 2d axis aligned rectangle of width=`w` and height=`h` with its origin of `x` and `y` being in the top left corner, the check whether a point `r` with position `rx` and `ry` lies in the rectangle would be:

```
if (rx >= x && rx <= x+w && ry >= y && ry <= ry+h)
{
    // we're inside the rectangle!
}
```

In simple terms this means:

- check if the point's x lies between the rectangle's x and x+w
- check if the point's y lies between the rectangle's y and y+h

In maths you could write it this way (doesn't work in JS though):

```
x <= rX <= x+w     ∧     y <= rY <= y+h
```

*The statements above imply that the coordinate system has the origin in the top left corner and the values increase towards bottom right.*

Comment: Thanks, that worked! It isn't that much different from the first thing i tried, so i'll try to understand that part a bit more.